# Use HTMLPurifier to filter out everything but instagrm embed code

Tags: htmlpurifier

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I have been trying to configure HTMLPurifier to accept instagram embed code.

Instagram embed code

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="7" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BSu5uVWhLWX/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">有人問我整理書櫃的方法  搬完家後我還沒時間整理，就把最近比較想讀的放在外圍這樣</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">囧星人（@shintarokyon）分享的貼文 於 <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2017-04-11T05:10:48+00:00">2017 年  4月 月 10 10:10下午 PDT</time> 張貼</p></div></blockquote>
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

HTMLPurifier setting

```
return [
'encoding'      => 'UTF-8',
'finalize'      => true,
'cachePath'     => storage_path('app/purifier'),
'cacheFileMode' => 0755,
'settings'      => [
    'default' => [
        'HTML.Doctype'             => 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional',
        'HTML.Allowed'             => 'div,b,strong,p,i,em,blockquote[class|style],a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|alt|src],iframe[src|width|height|class|frameborder]',
        'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align',
        'HTML.AllowedAttributes'   => 'style,src',
        'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => true,
        'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty'   => true,
        "HTML.SafeIframe"          => true,
        "URI.SafeIframeRegexp"     => "%^(http://|https://|//)(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/|api.soundcloud.com/tracks/)%",
    ],
    'test'    => [
        'Attr.EnableID' => true
    ]
],
```

I have been trying to  allow "style" in 'HTML.AllowedAttributes' setting.But it was not working.And tried to allowed css properties-'box-shadow'...etc,but some properties was not supported.

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: HTML Purifier has no means to analyse the JavaScript for safety, so from its perspective, there's no conceivably safe way to allow that `<script>` tag on your page. Consider a lateral solution: Since `//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js` is not parametrised (i.e. presumably the same for every embed code), why not just pull that part out of the purified HTML and add it to your page?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier/issues/32

Adding new properties is not supported by this package.